# Can I upgrade the processor in my Minix Neo Z83-4, and is this practical?

Tags: cpu, video-streaming, high-definition, dvr, minix

Is possible, and practical, to upgrade the processor in a Minix mini-computer?

Specifically, I am using my Minix Neo Z83-4 as a Playon server. I am subscribed to DirecTV Now, and to be able to DVR live shows, cast to Roku, skip commercials, etc. would be awesome. Out of the box, this setup actually works okay, but I didn't realize beforehand that a more powerful processor is required before Playon can stream or record in HD. (Standard definition on a high-def screen is not a pretty sight.)

If it is practical to try this, what should I be mindful of? I'm a software dev, but I have never built a computer before or anything like that. Might a more powerful processor be prone to overheating? Can I make a decent gain to my processing power and still have everything contained in a Minix body? Is this just a terrible idea to begin with?

Comment: These devices are not at all upgrade friendly. This would be practical only if some specific conditions were met. That would include availability of a suitable processor at a reasonable price (doubtful). Plus possession of the necessary special equipment and the considerable knowledge and skill to use it. You can obtain knowledge by asking questions but skill comes only with practice. This is far from simple. Paying someone to do this would raise the cost to prohibitive levels.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I may have some other, MUCh simpler options to do what I want to do here. Sounds like this is a DIY project for someone a little more practiced than I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are... no. The cherry trail is a BGA processor, soldered on to the motherboard, and its not going to be 'simple' in any way to do this. Assuming your motherboard firmware supports the new processor, *and* its the same package type and critically, you can actually do the soldering (usually done with special tools), maybe.

But for the average software dev (and not the hardcore electronics guru), its probably not worth the effort.